# Console Application not found on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just download visual studio community to my pc. When i opened the vs-2015 and create new Console application project. i can't find it any where under the c# we installed templates or any templates.

Thinking about to uninstall and install again but this not the first time i uninstall and install this, i did installed and uninstall few time but still can't find the web Console Application template.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I had the same _problem_. Turned out I started Blend for Visual Studio and not Visual Studio.

Comment: The Console Application only shows up when Visual C# is select in the left pane and not when something below it is selected.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and found the solution on [another site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ea10510-1a9c-4036-9b4b-1d25066c91ad/missing-c-console-template?forum=visualstudiogeneral). Here are the steps that need to be performed:

1. Open a Visual Studio command window with admin privileges. This can be done from Windows search after clicking on the Windows button (or Start button - depending on the OS) located in the lower left corner. Make sure that you don't have any Visual Studio project open before proceeding.
2. Type in prompt in the search box and select "Developer Command Prompt". Right click on this and select run with admin privileges.
3. In the command window Enter:

**cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE**

4. In the command window then enter:

**devenv /installvstemplates**

This worked for me and I was able to create a new console project after this.

With my version of VS 2015 community edition, upon install there was a Console Application (Package) template available, which I mistakenly thought was a Console Application template. This is not the case. It is a web console application project and I only discovered this after trying to access the File and Directory classes in System.IO from my code. The compiler kept on complaining:

Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Directory' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
MyProject.DNX Core 5.0  ...

It still complained after putting in a reference to System.IO and even after changing the offending line of code to:

```
string DataPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

A big clue here is the reference to DNX Core 5.0, which is an optimized run-time for ASP apps. It was at that point that I discovered that the Console Application (Package) template was also listed under the New Project window Templates / Visual C# / Web.

So, For others that may happen to find this post and think you are using a standard Console Application template, but have errors like "CS0234 The type or namespace "name" does not exist in the namespace..." then you could be using a Console Application (Package) template - which is probably not what you want and should be replaced by a regular Console Application. If you don't see it in the New Project window under Templates / Visual C#, then you should follow the steps above to install it.

**EDIT**

This is what my New Project window looks like after I performed the steps above:

[image]

Comparing this window with yours above, it appears to be somewhat different. Notice that "New Project" on my window is centered and for yours it is not. Also, at the bottom of the window yours has only Name, Location and Solution name, while my window adds a fourth item called Solution.

So, first thing, try clicking on Visual C# located in the left pane of your New Project window to see the templates available. Post that snapshot here. This can be done by selecting edit.

If you still don't see the Console Application template, then perhaps you downloaded a different version of Visual Studio 2015 than I did. So, here is the screen that pops up after selecting Help / About Microsoft Visual Studio on my system:

[image]

Compare this screen with yours and post a snapshot of your screen here. Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Bob for your answered.. i did open the “Develop Command Prompt for VS2015”.Type the “cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE” and press Enter. Then type "devenv /installvstemplates" and press Enter. unfortunately. it doesn't work at all, uninstalled and reinstalled about 10 times. still no luck

Comment: I have updated my answer with some additional ideas. Please take a look.

Comment: your solution does not work, it shows the same as before writing the commands you indicated

Answer (score 4):

Thanks again Bob for your time to explained it to me, i am really appreciate that, I uninstalled and installed again from this link [enter link description here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/post-install-vs?campaign=ct!!7A95E257A6564924A7805DF3A986D430), On my machine i have Visual Studio 2015(this one works) and Blend for Visual Studio 2015 is still missing template but i don't care it anymore if it work or not because i will use the one that works which is the Visual Studio 2015.
[image]

Comment: I didn't want to reinstall VS community version. It has installed both "Blend for visual studio" and "Visual Studio". I got fooled as I could see "Blend for visual studio" in the top of my start menu as it starts from "B". When I scrolled down/searched for Visual Studio, it was there :D Better to search for "Visual Studio" before trying to uninstall. Just a heads up, might work for you!

Comment: @MC_A Please accept Bob's answer as the solution by clicking the check mark next to it. His answer solved the issue for me as well.