# There is no "Console Application (Package)" project template in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have installed visual studio 2015 completely but I don't have "Console Application (Package)" template project. This must be under web section of Visual C#. But it doesn't.
I mean below project as you see in picture that I took from a book :

[image]

Do I have to install extra feature to get it ?

Comment: I think VS does not have the capability by itself of creating nuget packages, maybe this is using the NuGet Package extension? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/daf5c6db-386b-4994-bdd7-b6cd52f11b72

Comment: Is this related to NuGet packages ?

Comment: Yes, the type of project shown there is for creating a nuget package, look at the right pane description "A project template for creating a console application as a NuGet package". If you want to create just a console application then use Windows->Console application.

Comment: this is duplacte question . below is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962391/console-application-not-found-on-visual-studio-2015

Comment: It seems to be a part of "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web tools" extensions. Check if this extension is installed with all updates.

Comment: @NasimBahar it's not, that's not the same template.

Comment: Just a guess, may be the picture on the book is wrong, what the text says about the project type?

Comment: I've installed nuget from nuget.org but nothing changed. :|

Comment: And I have "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" extension installed.

Comment: These project templates target a very old version of .NETCore, back when it still used DNX.  Which is retired today.  The word PREVIEW is notable in your screenshot.  Pretty good odds that they were removed in the Community edition.  You'll probably have to download the up-to-date VS tools for .NETCore, wrapped in the [.NETCore SDK 1.0.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant . I downloaded .net core sdk 1.0.1 preview 2. what is the difference between .net core sdk and .net core and which one should i download? I pretty new to .net things ....

Comment: You need the SDK to get the VS tools to build a .NETCore program.  Do avoid targeting it just "because it is there", this is in perennial preview, buggy, incomplete and won't stabilize for a while.  If you are just starting out then you want to target something that you can get help with from Google and ask questions about that don't have a "you can't do that" answer.